# For a linear map $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ what are the inner products $[\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,]$ such that $\alpha, T\alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, linear-transformations

> For a given linear transformation $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, how does one obtain all inner products $[\,,\,]$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $$[\alpha, T\alpha] = 0 ?$$

I know that for $T(x_{1},x_{2}) = (-x_{2},x_{1})$ by the standard product on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (,)  we have $(\alpha, T\alpha) = 0$ $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and a positive multiple of a inner product is still a inner product so by this particular case, can I compute all the others with that condition?

Comment: Do you mean for the particular transformation $T(x_1, x_2) = (-x_2, x_1)$ or for a general transformation $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$?

Comment: General $T$, i thought that all $T$ in general are similar of this particular case. I think its wrong but i just cant think in another case to prove this to me or how to solve the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any inner product on $\mathbb R^2$ is of the form $\langle x,y\rangle =x^tAy$ for some positive-definite symmetric matrix $A$.
If you want that $\langle x,Tx\rangle=0$ for $T(x)=Bx$, you obtain the condition $x^tABx=0$. So it boils down to find all positive-definite symmetric matrices $A$ such that $x^tABx=0$ for all $x$.

Let me give an example. Taking $A=\begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ b &c\end{pmatrix}$ you get
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=ax_1y_1+bx_1y_2+bx_2y_1+cx_2y_2.
$$
For the transformation $T(x_1,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$ you obtain
$$
b(x_1^2-x_2^2)=(a-c)x_1x_2
$$
for all $(x_1,x_2)$, which gives $b=0$ and $a=c$ (and positive so that $A$ is positive-definite).

Comment: is there a simple way to compute the form of that symmetric matrices of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: in the general case

Comment: My first paragraph considers the general case: you have to find all positive-definite symmetric matrices $A$ such that $AB=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For any particular transformation $$T = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d},$$ we can write a general bilinear form $[\,\cdot\, , \,\cdot\,]$ as $B = \pmatrix{P&Q\\Q&R}$, so that
$$[\alpha, T \alpha] = \alpha^T BT \alpha,$$
where we have denoted $\alpha = \pmatrix{x\\y}$. Now, by polarizing we can see that this quantity is zero for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R^2$ iff
$$BT = \pmatrix{P&Q\\Q&R} \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = 0 .$$
If we write out the four matrix entries of the product, we get a system of four (generally independent) equations in three unknowns $P, Q, R$, so for a general transformation $T$ the only bilinear form for which $[\alpha, T\alpha] = 0$ for all $\alpha$ is the zero form, which is not an inner product. So, for general transformations there are no such inner products with the desired property. (As usual, if we have some nonzero solution $(P, Q, R)$, it corresponds to an inner product iff $P > 0$ and $PR > Q^2$.)

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but can you conclude that $BT = 0$? I thought that was only true on complex vector spaces.

Comment: I think so, but please correct me if I'm missing something: By polarizing the quadratic form $\alpha \mapsto [\alpha, T\alpha]$ we get the bilinear form $(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto [\beta, T\alpha]$. Then, $[\alpha, T\alpha] = 0$ for all $\alpha$ iff the quadratic form is zero iff the bilinear form is zero iff the matrix representation of the bilinear for is zero. But the matrix representation of the bilinear form is just $BT$.