# Find all inner products on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

> Let $( | )$ be the standard inner product  on $\mathbb{R^2}$ , and let $T$ be the linear operator $T(x_1,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$. Now $T$ is 'rotation through $90°$' and has the property that $(\alpha |T\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ . Find all inner products $[   |   ]$  on $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $[\alpha | T\alpha]=0$ for each $\alpha$.

**My Attempt** since $\alpha\in \mathbb{R^2}$. So let us assume $\alpha=(x,y)$ then

$(\alpha |T\alpha)=((x,y) | T(x,y))=-xy+xy=0$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. So I think we have as many inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$ as positive real numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Stating how many inner products satisfying the condition there are is not the same as *finding* all inner products satisfying the condition.

Comment: Aren't you using the standard inner product in your argument again when you say $\langle (x,y) \, | \, T(x,y)\rangle=-xy+xy$

Comment: @Anurag Yes. How to start

Comment: Or try this as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633672/for-a-linear-map-t-bbb-r2-to-bbb-r2-what-are-the-inner-products-cdo?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Every inner product over $\Bbb R^2$ can be written in the form $[\alpha|\beta] = (S\alpha|S\beta)$ for an invertible linear map $S:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: why, It can be written in the form.